# Removing Route 53 record upon CloudFormation cancellation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

How can I run a script to clean up when my CloudFormation is cancelled? I have an environment that adds a record in Route 53. When deleting this development stack, I want it to remove the dev record I added during init.

Is this possible?

Comment: Was this record added by CloudFormation? or you are adding it from somewhere else? If CF, it should delete the record when you delete the stack.

Comment: Did you modify the record after CF created it?

Comment: It's being added in a script that is being run in userdata. Apparently, I didn't know you could set a record within the template itself... thanks for that tip!